# Bash prevent variabile to being executed as input

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where i need to send queries to a rest api server using curl.

I'm tring to do this:

```
$(curl -m100000000000000000000000000000000 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "create table hdfs.bigdata.`databases/'$cleantn'/'$timestamp'` AS (SELECT * FROM dfs.`'$tempfile'`)"}' http://localhost:8047/query.json)
```

I can't get it to work. The * is being evaluated from bash

putting it in a variabile still dosen't work

```
query='{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "create table hdfs.bigdata.`databases/'$cleantn'/'$timestamp'` AS (SELECT * FROM dfs.`'$tempfile'`)"}'
$(curl -m100000000000000000000000000000000 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d''$query'' http://localhost:8047/query.json)
#or
$(curl -m100000000000000000000000000000000 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"$query" http://localhost:8047/query.json)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query='{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "create table hdfs.bigdata.`databases/'$cleantn'/'$timestamp'` AS (SELECT * FROM dfs.`'$tempfile'`)"}'
```

Swap the quotation marks. bash won't process anything in speech quotes `""` or with the escape prepended `\`

The above becomes:

```
query="{'queryType':'SQL', 'query': 'create table hdfs.bigdata.`databases/'$cleantn'/'$timestamp'` AS (SELECT * FROM dfs.`'$tempfile'`)'}"
```